# What's the difference between 'I would like to do' and 'I would want to do'?

Tags: grammar

I would like to do that.

and

I would want to do that.

What is the difference between them? I think these two are almost the same usually?

And if I were to ask someone to my place, should I say 'would you like to come' or 'would you want to come'?

Comment: What’s the difference between “want” and “like”?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Yes both sentences are same usually, but difference in both  is that one with indirect speech and second with direct speech.

I would like to do that.  [Indirect speech]

and

I would want to do that.  [Direct speech]

Comment: @185535485 You’ve accepted this answer but it is wrong.  This is not about direct vs indirect speech.  Please don’t come away from this thinking this is the correct answer.

Comment: This answer is completely false.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are examples of subjunctive verb usage. Both present an hypothetical situation; an uncertainty.

If you remove the uncertainty by removing "would", the differences become clearer.

I like to do that.
I want to do that.

The former declares something the writer enjoys doing; the latter something the writer wishes to do.

The subjunctive "would" sets both into a conditional setting; there is something which must occur for the writer to obtain the situation in which he can "like" or "want".

If we go to the fair, I would like to buy a corndog.

If we go to the fair, I would want to ride a pony.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The near-paraphrases are actually

- '*I'd like to do that*'

and

- '*I want to do that*'.

The former perhaps shows less resolve  / a belief that there is less likelihood of 'it' happening.

- '*I would want to do that*' is either a protasis in a conditional sentence
- *If I were a gifted violinist, I would want to be in a distinguished orchestra*

or very rarefied

(compare "*I need to see the owner of this yacht*." __ "*That would be me*.")

while

- 'I'd / I would like to do that' *may* be a protasis
- ('*I'd  like to do that if I could be sure I wouldn't fall off the horse at a fence*')

but doesn't have to be, just airing a (very to vanishingly possible) desire

- ('*I'd like to have a half of cider, please*' ... ... ...  '*I'd like to be the first man on Pluto*').